# Placeholder animation while loading image from the network

Tags: android, animation, android-imageview

I'm working with a bunch of `ImageView`s and most of them are updated dynamically. I check if the image exists on a local storage drive and if it's not present I download the image. While this is all happening I create a `CardView` and display it on the screen. What I would like to know is how do I set my ImageView to have a placeholder animation (the circle loading one) while my image is downloading? I have tried using `.gif` but as I have read the animation is not supported in android "from the box". What are other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a separate view: ProgressBar. Something like this for each image cell:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ImageView>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">
    </ProgressBar>
</RelativeLayout>
```

ProgressBar isn't very aptly named, since it can be styled to look like other shapes then a bar. This particular style makes it look like a circular loading spinner. Just make sure to set the spinner visiblity to View.INVISIBLE once your image is loaded.

Comment: I have been using `ProgressBar` in other situatuins but I didn't think it was eligible for replacing `ImageView`. I will try and say if it's goin OK

Comment: All tested, all fine :) I will now need to make it look like a better layout but it must look quite nice soon! Thanks a lot